# Using typedef variable (C)

Tags: c, typedef

Hello I am having some trouble using this variable in my program:

`typedef char chessPos[2];`

How exactly should I be scanning into it, using it in functions, and how would I properly make and use an array of this type?

to scan it i tried using:

`scanf("%c%c", currPos[0], currPos[1]);`

But I get this warning:
`scanf: format string %c requires an argument of type 'char*', but variadic argument 1/2 has type 'int'`

thank you for your help!

Comment: Your beginner learning material (book, tutorial or class) should have told you that you need to use the pointer-to operator `&` for values.

Comment: Aside: you might need to put a space before the first `%c` (to waste any previous newline) as well as passing the *addresses* of the `char` variables. `scanf(" %c%c", &currPos[0], &currPos[1]);`

Comment: In addition to pts'  answer below, you also have an error in the declaration of chessPos. It should simply be defined without typedef: char chessPos[2]; 
Typedef defines a (user-defined) type, such as a struct, or a function pointer. Plain variables (or arrays thereof) need no typedef. They only need the type (in your case char) before them.
The scanf should then look like in the previous comment)

Comment: @WStanzl presumably OP has `chessPos currPos;` in their code. I too would question the need for a `typedef` but in my early days I did find it useful sometimes when I was having trouble with more complicated syntax.

Comment: @Weather Vane True, I get your point, it would not have occured to me in that way; I make my typedefs always SOMETING_t. Let's see what OP's response will be...

Answer (score 3):

This is one way:

```
chessPos currPos;
if (scanf("%c%c", currPos, currPos + 1) != 2) abort();
```

This is another way:

```
chessPos currPos;
int i;
if ((i = getchar()) == EOF) abort();
currPos[0] = i;
if ((i = getchar()) == EOF) abort();
currPos[1] = i;
```

Your original code didn't work, because the `%c` format specifier expects a `char*`, i.e. a pointer to a `char`, and `currPos[1]` is the value. We need its address instead, e.g. `currPos + 1` or, equivalently, `&currPos[1]`.

Answer (score 0):

Newer `typedef` pointers or arrays. It is a very bad practice.

To get an address of the `n`th element of an `array` you need to:

- use pointer arithmetic: `array + n`
- use the `&` operator: `&array[n]`

In your case:

```
scanf("%c%c", &currPos[0], &currPos[1]);
/*  or */
scanf("%c%c", currPos, currPos +1);
```